# How to compute the first etale cohomology of a constructible torsion-free sheaf?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, constructible-sheaves

I am interested in the following example!

Let $k$ be a field, let $X_0$ be the scheme $\mathrm{Spec}R$ with $R_0=k[x,y]/(xy)$, let $R$ be the strict Hensilian localalisation of $R_0$ at the origin and $X=\mathrm{Spec}R$, we define a sheaf $F$ on $X$ by $F(U)=\mathbb{Z}^2$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ for $U$ open in $X$ depending on if $U$ contains the origin or not (hence the stalk of $F$ is $\mathbb{Z}^2$ at the origin, and $\mathbb{Z}$ at other points). The restriction maps for defining $F$ are given by $\mathbb{Z}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}:(m,n)\mapsto m+n$ (in fact the sheaf comes from the log structure associated to the embedding $X_0\subset \mathbb{A}^2$ ). Since $X$ is strict Hensilian, we have $H^1(X,F)=0$.

Now consider the projection $p:\mathbb{G}_{m,R}\rightarrow X=\mathrm{Spec}R$.

What would be the group $H^1(\mathbb{G}_{m,R},p^*F)$?

Maybe an easier version, is $H^1(\mathbb{G}_{m,R},\mathbb{Z})$ zero?

We do know $H^1(\mathbb{G}_{m},\mathbb{Z})=H^1(\mathrm{Spec}R,\mathbb{Z})=0$!

Comment: What are the restriction maps and why is $F$ a sheaf? Do you mean $F = \mathbb Z \oplus j_* \mathbb Z$, where $j \colon \{0\} \to X$ is the inclusion?

Comment: @R. van Dobben de Bruyn Thanks for the reminder! I have added the restriction maps, I think it's different from the one you guessed

Comment: I think that the thing you wrote down might be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z \oplus j_* \mathbb Z$: if we write $(a,b) = (m+n,n)$ (this is an automorphism of $\mathbb Z^2$), then the restriction map is just $(a,b) \mapsto a$.

Comment: @ de Bruyn: Yes, I agree with you. They are isomorphic to each other